# Calculating number of words from input text

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I split the input paragraph by `.` and store it in an array like this:

```
string[] totalSentences = inputPara.Split('.')
```

then the function below is called which calculates total number of Words from each sentence like this:

```
public void initParaMatrix()
{
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalSentences.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] words = totalSentences[i].Split();
        size = size + words.Length;
        //rest of the logic here...
    }
    matrixSize = size;
    paraMatrix = new string[matrixSize, matrixSize];
}
```

**`paraMatrix`** is a 2D matrix equal to length of all words which I need to make in my logic.
The problem here is when I input only one sentence which has 5 words, the `size` variable gets the value 7. I tried the debugger and I was getting total of **2** sentences instead of **1**.

Sentence 1. "Our present ideas about motion." **> this is actual sentence which have only 5 words**

Sentence 2. " " **> this is the exact second sentence I'm getting.**

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Why I'm getting two sentences here and how is size getting value 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes perfect sense.  If the second sentence has nothing but a " ", and you split along the " ", then you'll have two empty strings as a result.  The easiest thing to do here is change the line you do the split, and add a trim:

```
string[] words = totalSentences[i].Trim().Split();
```

I don't know what version of Split that you're using since it accepts no parameters, but if you use `String.Split` you can set the second parameter so that empty entries are automatically removed by using the option `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Comment: The `Split(params char[] separator)` overload can be called without passing any parameters.  The default behavior is to split on white space characters.  They should use the `Split(char[] separator, StringSplitOptions options)` overload instead.

Comment: @Daniel Gimenez: I used the `Trim()` method but now I'm getting the total count as **6**. But when I remove the `.` at the end of sentence (which I can't do in real scenario) the problem is solved. What's the problem with having a period at the end and why its causing the count to increase?

Comment: @Daniel Gimenez: `StringSplit.RemoveEmptryEntries` did the work for me. Like this `string[] words = totalSentences[i].Split(new[]{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not resetting the size integer to zero. So that's why you get 7 for the second sentence.
For the second sentence, which is a space, try inputPara.Trim() which should remove the space at the end of the string.

Comment: I tried the `inputPara.Trim()` but I'm getting still count as **6**

Comment: You need to move the size = 0; inside the first for-loop

Comment: Well I can't do that. I need the total count in my logic. [Daniel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27927455/3621001) solved my problem. Thanks for the help though.